# Как измерить время выполнения консольной программы Swift?

Tags: swift, отладка

Решаю задачки по олимпиадному программированию. Естественно, там есть ограничение на выполнение.

Как я решал эту проблему на питоне: `time python3 py.py` и получал результат с точностью до сотых секунды
А в Swift как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755558/measure-elapsed-time-in-swift

Comment: @schmidt9 спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@schmidt9 спасибо!

Актуально с **Swift3**

```swift
import CoreFoundation

class ParkBenchTimer {
    let startTime:CFAbsoluteTime
    var endTime:CFAbsoluteTime?

    init() {
        startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    }

    func stop() -> CFAbsoluteTime {
        endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        return duration!
    }

    var duration: CFAbsoluteTime? {
        if let endTime = endTime {
            return endTime - startTime
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let timer = ParkBenchTimer()
// сюда вставить свой код

// после своего кода
print("\(timer.stop()) seconds.")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]